# Collection of short-stories for kids/teens in German

Tags: identification-request, german-language

Around 13-15 years ago I had a book (or 2!) which featured a collection of short stories.

It was written in German; I sadly remember neither the name of the book, nor the author's or publisher's name. What I do remember is, that it featured stories of:

- Münchhausen
- Schildbürger
- Till Eulenspiegel
- I believe some dinosaur stories

It was a hardcover book, that's for sure.
It also featured a couple of pictures to support the stories.

It is not the book "Der Struwwelpeter".

I'd highly appreciate any tips, be it bookcovers, names, authors..

Answer (score 2):

Would it be **"Till Eulenspiegel. Münchhausen. Die Schildbürger"**

It's a hardcover book and sorry I am not German and don't speak a drop of German but I am going to guess its this because its a hard cover book with several short stories.

I found the book on [Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Till-Eulenspiegel-M%C3%BCnchhausen-Schildb%C3%BCrger-einem/dp/B004WCWPNC).

Please tell me if I am wrong; this is just a researched guess.

Comment: I believe not, sadly. I've looked at a lot of cover-arts for this one and descriptions, but it doesn't really fit. It's close tho..

Comment: Apologies then I just had a guess, Good luck trying to find it!

Comment: It's impossible to check whether that Amazon.de link points to the book you had in mind; no title information is available there.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this question is that there have been so many children's books that combined the stories of Münchhausen, Till Eulenspiegel and Die Schildbürger. Below are a few examples, each of which is a hardcover edition. (I have not included the links to Amazon.de, since these will become invalid over time.)

(1) *Die schönsten Vorleseklassiker: Till Eulenspiegel, Münchhausen, Rübezahl, Die Schildbürger. Vorlesebuch und Geschenkbuch*, published by Gondolino in 2013 (but this may be a reprint).

[image: Bookcover of the above book; in addition to the words from the tittle, it also shows colourful illustrations for each of the four stories listed on the cover]

(2) *Narrenstreiche - Münchhausen; Die Schildbürger; Till Eulenspiegel - Drei lustige Erzählungen, für die Jugend bearbeitet von Friedrich Hanke*, published by Verlag Jugendhort in 1920. See the bookcover below.

[image: Bookcover with the title 'Narrenstreiche' and an illustration in black, red and white]

(3) *Till Eulenspiel & Münchhausen & Die Schildbürger*, edited or retold by Kurt Eigl and illustrated by Ernst Schrom, published by Bertelsmann in 1962. See the bookcover below.

[image: Bookcover with the title 'Till Eulenspiel - Münchhausen - Die Schildbürger' and an illustration for each of the stories]

(4) *Narrenstreiche. Münchhausen. Die Schildbürger. Till Eulenspiegel*, edited or retold by Hanke and illustrated by Hanetzog; published by Jugendhort in 1910 (some editions of the same volume were published earlier or without a year of publication). See the bookcover below.

[image: Bookcover with the title 'Narrenstreiche' and an illustration of Münchhausen dangling from a rope attached to the moon]

(5) *Erich Kästner erzählt: Münchhausen, Gullivers Reisen, Till Eulenspiegel, Die Schildbürger, Don Quichotte* Cecillie Dressler Verlag, 1975. See the bookcover below.

[image: Cover with the above book title and an illustration of Münchhausen flying over a battlefield on a cannonball]